# DB2 ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815 clob field

Tags: jpa, db2

The problem happens in a DB2 database. I tried with the different db2 databases 97 101 and 105.

The JPA entities work perfectly. One registry is saved properly in database. The problem is when a query is done and one of the items contains a NULL value on a BLOB column.

The field is defined with these JPA annotations:

```
@Lob
@Field
@FieldBridge(impl = ArtificerTikaBridge.class)
@Nullable
@Column(length = 20971520, nullable = true)
public byte[] getContent() {
    return content;
}
```

This is the exception:

```
11:07:55,836 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-11)         artificera0_.name asc fetch first 21 rows only
11:07:56,060 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-11) SQL Error: -4461, SQLState: 42815
11:07:56,061 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-11) [jcc][t4][1092][11644][4.15.113] Conversión de datos no válida: Tipo incorrecto de la columna de resultados para la conversión solicitada. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
11:07:56,282 ERROR [org.artificer.server.atom.services.AbstractFeedResource] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-11) !!Error trying to create an Artifact Feed.!!: org.artificer.common.error.ArtificerServerException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.artificer.repository.hibernate.HibernateUtil$HibernateTask.execute(HibernateUtil.java:95) [artificer-repository-hibernate-1.0.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:1.0.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.artificer.repository.hibernate.query.HibernateQuery.executeQuery(HibernateQuery.java:73) [artificer-repository-hibernate-1.0.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:1.0.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.artificer.repository.query.AbstractArtificerQueryImpl.executeQuery(AbstractArtificerQueryImpl.java:105) [artificer-repository-1.0.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:1.0.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.artificer.server.QueryServiceImpl.query(QueryServiceImpl.java:76) [classes:]
    at org.artificer.server.atom.services.AbstractFeedResource.createArtifactFeed(AbstractFeedResource.java:67) [classes:]
    at org.artificer.server.atom.services.QueryResource.queryFromPost(QueryResource.java:113) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:168) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:541) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:523) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:125) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.artificer.repository.filter.ServletCredentialsFilter.doFilter(ServletCredentialsFilter.java:45) [artificer-repository-1.0.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:1.0.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.overlord.commons.auth.filters.SamlBearerTokenAuthFilter.doFilterChain(SamlBearerTokenAuthFilter.java:264) [overlord-commons-auth-2.0.17.Final.jar:2.0.17.Final]
    at org.overlord.commons.auth.filters.SamlBearerTokenAuthFilter.doFilter(SamlBearerTokenAuthFilter.java:238) [overlord-commons-auth-2.0.17.Final.jar:2.0.17.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.artificer.server.filters.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:59) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:512) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.ClusteredSessionValve.handleRequest(ClusteredSessionValve.java:134) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-17.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-17]
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.ClusteredSessionValve.invoke(ClusteredSessionValve.java:99) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-17.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-17]
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.JvmRouteValve.invoke(JvmRouteValve.java:92) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-17.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-17]
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.LockingValve.invoke(LockingValve.java:64) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-17.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-17]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-17.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-17]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-17.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-17]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-17.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:277) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler$3.getResultList(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:254) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.artificer.repository.hibernate.query.ArtificerToHibernateQueryVisitor.query(ArtificerToHibernateQueryVisitor.java:187) [artificer-repository-hibernate-1.0.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:1.0.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.artificer.repository.hibernate.query.HibernateQuery.executeQuery(HibernateQuery.java:93) [artificer-repository-hibernate-1.0.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:1.0.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.artificer.repository.hibernate.query.HibernateQuery.access$000(HibernateQuery.java:39) [artificer-repository-hibernate-1.0.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:1.0.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.artificer.repository.hibernate.query.HibernateQuery$1.doExecute(HibernateQuery.java:76) [artificer-repository-hibernate-1.0.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:1.0.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.artificer.repository.hibernate.query.HibernateQuery$1.doExecute(HibernateQuery.java:73) [artificer-repository-hibernate-1.0.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:1.0.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.artificer.repository.hibernate.HibernateUtil$HibernateTask.execute(HibernateUtil.java:73) [artificer-repository-hibernate-1.0.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:1.0.0.Final-redhat-4]
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2395) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2358) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:198) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1194) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:268) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 57 more
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][t4][1092][11644][4.15.113] Conversión de datos no válida: Tipo incorrecto de la columna de resultados para la conversión solicitada. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:696)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:120)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jc.U(jc.java:2105)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ResultSet.getClob(ResultSet.java:1357)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ResultSet.getClob(ResultSet.java:1746)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.getClob(WrappedResultSet.java:783)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.ClobTypeDescriptor$1.doExtract(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:60) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:265) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:261) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:251) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.getResultRow(QueryLoader.java:446) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:747) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:949) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:917) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:348) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2550) [hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.17.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 65 more

11:07:56,304 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/artificer-ui].[org.artificer.ui.server.services.ArtificerApplication]] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet org.artificer.ui.server.services.ArtificerApplication threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.artificer.ui.client.shared.exceptions.ArtificerUiException: [jcc][t4][1092][11644][4.15.113] Conversión de datos no válida: Tipo incorrecto de la columna de resultados para la conversión solicitada. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:364) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:232) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:556) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:523) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:125) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.overlord.commons.gwt.server.filters.BusAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BusAuthenticationFilter.java:61) [overlord-commons-gwt-2.0.17.Final.jar:2.0.17.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.overlord.commons.auth.filters.HttpRequestThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(HttpRequestThreadLocalFilter.java:58) [overlord-commons-auth-2.0.17.Final.jar:2.0.17.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.overlord.commons.gwt.server.filters.PostAuthenticationRedirectFilter.doFilter(PostAuthenticationRedirectFilter.java:48) [overlord-commons-gwt-2.0.17.Final.jar:2.0.17.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.overlord.commons.auth.filters.PicketLinkAuthWrapperFilter.doFilter(PicketLinkAuthWrapperFilter.java:73) [overlord-commons-auth-2.0.17.Final.jar:2.0.17.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.artificer.ui.server.filters.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:65) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.overlord.commons.gwt.server.filters.GWTCacheControlFilter.doFilter(GWTCacheControlFilter.java:76) [overlord-commons-gwt-2.0.17.Final.jar:2.0.17.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.ClusteredSessionValve.handleRequest(ClusteredSessionValve.java:134) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-17.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-17]
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.ClusteredSessionValve.invoke(ClusteredSessionValve.java:99) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-17.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-17]
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.JvmRouteValve.invoke(JvmRouteValve.java:92) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-17.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-17]
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.LockingValve.invoke(LockingValve.java:64) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-17.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-17]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-17.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: org.artificer.ui.client.shared.exceptions.ArtificerUiException: [jcc][t4][1092][11644][4.15.113] Conversión de datos no válida: Tipo incorrecto de la columna de resultados para la conversión solicitada. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
    at org.artificer.ui.server.services.ArtifactSearchService.search(ArtifactSearchService.java:110) [classes:]
    at org.artificer.ui.server.services.ArtifactSearchService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.search(ArtifactSearchService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:168) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:541) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    ... 41 more
```